# Fantasy trilogy with dragons

Tags: story-identification, magic, dragons, demons

Back in 2008 I read a trilogy of fantasy books. The series was about a man who had slain the last dragon that had been seen in the land and his wife, who was a low powered witch. The first book starts with the main character being called by the king or some higher lord to kill a new dragon that has taken over a gold mine. Dragons are fully sentient and powerful magic users. This new dragon is a very old black dragon and ends up getting into a kind of relationship with the wife. At the end of the first book the dragon turns her into a dragon but she ends up changing her mind and becoming a human again to be with her husband.

The next two books were about the man, wife, and the dragon fighting a demon I think. Another thing, dragons like gold because they can sing to it and it resonates really well. Dragons also don't breath fire, they spray some kind of acid, or maybe a highly oxidizing fluid.

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176268.Dragonsbane? Reluctant hero faces black dragon according to the blurb.

Comment: @Richard Gold picks up the music of dragons in those books. Also The second book does revolve around killing demons. The first book does match the OP's story as well.

Comment: See preview [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=g07k3HKuwQIC&pg=PT205&dq=%22gold+pick+up+the+music%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a_LDVJ37K43nsASdmYDwCA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22gold%20pick%20up%20the%20music%22&f=false)

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - Nice one. Team effort.

Comment: I read that second sentence to mean that he killed the last dragon in the land AND his wife.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [Winterland](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176268.Dragonsbane) trilogy of books by Barbara Hambly.

The blurb for the first one mentions a reluctant ex-dragon-slayer, a black dragon, a goldmine and a request from a King.

> When the Black Dragon seized the Deep of Ylferdun, young Gareth braved
>   the far Winterlands to find John Aversin, Dragonsbane -- the only
>   living man ever to slay a dragon. In return for the promise of the
>   King to send help to the Winterlands, Aversin agreed to attempt the
>   nearly impossible feat again.
>
> With them, to guard them on the haunted trip south, went Jenny
>   Waynest, a half-taught sorceress and mother of Aversin's sons.
>
> But at the decadent Court, nothing was as expected. Rebellion
>   threatened the land. Zyerne, a sorceress of seemingly unlimited power,
>   held the King under an evil spell, and he refused to see them.
>   Meantime, the dragon fed well on the knights who had challenged him.

There's also a [mention](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=g07k3HKuwQIC&pg=PT205&dq=%22gold%20pick%20up%20the%20music%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a_LDVJ37K43nsASdmYDwCA&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=wife&f=false) of the dragon spraying acid and singing to his gold. Also, the hero's wife is described as "mage-born".

The blurb for the [second book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176245.Dragonshadow) mentions demons and an alliance between the heroes and a dragon:

> Lord John Aversin--with the help of his mageborn wife, Jenny Waynest--
>   has fought and defeated two dragons, earning the title of Dragonsbane.
>   But there are creatures more terrifying than dragons. Demonspawn from
>   a dark dimension have learned to drink the magic--and the souls--of
>   mages and dragons alike, turning their victims into empty vessels. And
>   now they've stolen John and Jenny's mageborn son, twelve-year-old Ian.
>
> In desperation, John seeks the help of the eldest and strongest
>   dragon: Morkeleb the Black. But the demons have allies, too: a vast
>   army poised to plunge the Realm into civil war. In the coming
>   struggle, Morkeleb will sacrifice what he values most.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much

Comment: http://youtu.be/mG9xNjQf6gw?t=20s